# Javascript client for REST API

Tags: rest, design-patterns, javascript, yeoman

I am trying to write a Javascript client for a web application which provides a REST API to interact with the application. I want to do this in a very advanced way like with a proven stack of tools and methodologies available in Javascript.

Most of the guides about javascript client library development I found in the web are application oriented which have a view part( I mean HTML part ). What I needed is like a client library with some methods which can be used to develop web applications. So I don't want to depend this library with any other javascript library like JQuery, Backbone etc.

I have gone through lot of design patterns available in javascript, especially patterns mentioned in [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) a book by Addy Osmani. And after all I got confused, I couldn't decide which one to follow.

What I have in mind is like following:

- Initialize the library with some key and secret (This can be compared to declaring object for a class in php).
- There will be a data persistence unit which will keep the authenticated user's identity over a predefined amount of time like sessions in php. User data will be stored in cookies or local-storage. Also there will be provisions to override the methods of this unit so that user can implement their own storage mechanism. A reference to this unit will also be passed during library initialization.
- Keep a global request method which handles all the API requests associated with the library(This can be compared to a method of the main class in php)
- Define all the API methods encapsulated into different units according to the area of application it dealing with. This each unit will have a constructor method which defines some default properties to the unit( This can be compared to defining models in php which will fetch or save data from the application with API ). Each of this unit can be inherited from a super unit which provides some default properties and methods.

After reading some blogs and articles I have decided to use yeoman for library development. May be I can use some yeoman community javascript library generators to start the development.

As I described above I think what I needed is like: a class which keeps a single instance throughout the application which can be used to refer all the models and functions in the models. For this may be I can go with the singleton module pattern, but I am not fully sure about how to make use of it to my requirement.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!